# Is placing a DIV tag between list tags valid?

Tags: html, css

Like this?

```
<li>Menu1</li><div></div>
<li>Menu2</li><div></div>
```

My reason for doing this is to style the div using CSS to make a separator with a gradient.

Comment: Maybe add empty li tags with a class which you can give your style too

Comment: No - @user1209203 And why you need to add them? If you want some style, just add a `span` and make it `display:block;` to give it the characteristic of a div.

Comment: I'll just use image backgrounds, I'd hoped to use only CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You can check for yourself here: http://validator.w3.org/

You *might* be able to get a similar result using the CSS pseudo-element `::after`, depending on how you're styling your `<li>`s.

E.g.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

li::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/nUZpy/

Apply gradient backgrounds as desired.

Note that to support IE8, you'll need to use the older syntax `:after` instead, and IE 7 doesn't support this pseudo-element at all.

Comment: That's a very neat solution can I avoid adding the pseudo element to the last list item though?

Comment: @user1209203: yes, spot on. Note that `:not()` isn't supported by IE8. If you want to support IE8, you could use `:before` instead of `::after`, and add `li:first-child:before {display: none;}` (I think).

Comment: I've decided to be brave and ditch IE8 support now, it only accounts for 5% of users according to the latest numbers.

Comment: @user1209203: good stuff. If it's within your responsibility, track visitors to the site once it's launched to see what kind of IE 8 numbers you get.

Answer (score 2):

No, this HTML structure is invalid.

Permitted contents for a [`<ul>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html) are zero or more [`<li>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li) elements

***Reference:***
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model

Answer (score 1):

No! Check it on: http://validator.w3.org/

**EDIT** Validate this code to see that it's not valid:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <div></div>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <div></div>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: <marquee> works without any problems too, that doesn't mean it should be used ;)

Comment: @StefanBrendle: always? In all circumstances? No problems ever? Entirely consistently between browsers? You sure?

Comment: Just because something renders properly doesnt mean it is valid HTML

Comment: Validation Output: 2 Errors
Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: I think I can get the effect by moving the divs inside the li tag

Comment: Yes, this is the best option to go for. +1

Comment: Edited post for people who don't understand that they need to validate this code to see that it is not valid :)

Answer (score 1):

you better to use like this,

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu1</li>
        <li><div></div></li>
        <li>Menu2</li>
        <div></div>
    </ul>
</body>
```